# Installing Ubuntu after Win 8, do I have to be careful?

Tags: installation, windows, bootloader, windows-8

Here is a System with Win 8 on HDD1. There is a second HDD and I thought I install Ubuntu 12.10 on this one.

Im not using Win 8, but other people are. So after installing Ubuntu, Win 8 should be working also. Do I have to be careful or just installing Ubuntu on HDD2 and everything will work fine? The bootloader will automaticly allow users to choose between win 8 and ubuntu? Any suggestions? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably won't be any issues, but make sure and back up any important files in win 8 first. Windows 8 has a good dual boot manager, so as long as you don't format or overwrite anything, I don't think you will have a problem. I have dual booted windows 8 and xp without any problems.